# ant groovy task stdout output

Tags: ant, groovy, stdout, stderr

Inside of my ant script (which is startet with the `-q` (quiet) cli option) I start a groovy script like that:

```
<groovy src="${groovy.script.filepath}">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="path/to/groovy/src/"/>
    </classpath>
    <arg line="-arg 1 -arg 2"/>
</groovy>
```

My groovy script looks like this:

```
//some imports

class MyClass {
    static void main(args) {
        System.out.println("Im not beeing printed!")
        System.err.println("But I am printed, but on stdout!")
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

I expected both the outputs to be displayed like when I do `<echo level="default">...</echo>` or `<echo level="error">...</echo>`. However the `System.out` one is not printed at all and the `System.err` one is printed on stdout.

Why is that and how can I make groovy print on stdout and stderr like when using ants `echo` task?